# Можно ли вмешаться в работу одной программы через другую?

Tags: c, apache-modules

У меня есть утилита htpasswd для web-сервера Apache, которая создает учетную запись(имя пользователя и пароль).

От меня требуется разработать программу которая должна быть встроена в алгоритм работы утилиты htpasswd и проверять, чтобы пароли пользователя были длиннее 10 символов. В случае несоответствия условию, пароль можно ввести заново.

Вопрос: можно ли с помощью отдельно созданной программы вмешаться в работу htpasswd, не трогая исходники самой утилиты?
Или же это возможно осуществить, только работая с исходниками htpasswd?

Comment: Нет, но вы можете просто написать программу-обертку, которая будет отклонять невалидный ввод